# Can't get fancyhdr to work (nothing happens)

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, templates

Basicaly, all I want to do is to put page numbers on the bottom of the page. I'm using the fancyhdr package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,openright,twoside,a4paper,english,brazilian]{abntex2}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
         colorlinks,
         linkcolor={black!80!black},
         citecolor={blue!50!black},
         urlcolor={blue!80!black}
        }

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}

\let\footruleskip\undefined
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
```

The problem is, nothing happens. I don't get any errors, but the page number doesn't show up. What's happening?

Comment: Please note, that one should load `hyperref` last. There are few packages which have to be loaded later, but not that many.

Comment: You should probably read the manual for that particular class. It is build on the `memoir` class which has its own better integrated system for handling page styles. But crucially: it automatically starts the document in frontmatter where the class has set the header and footer to nothing. Try starting your text with `\mainmatter`

Comment: @daleif but this way it doesn't use the `fancyhdr` but the memoir one (and if he wants to use `fancyhdr`...)

Comment: @Skillmon the OP should not be using `fancyhdr` at all.

Comment: @daleif correct (which is why you got my upvote on both, your comment and your answer), but if he insists on it... (Sorry, I did not want to start a discussion in any way)

Comment: @Skillmon no problem. Often, when using unknown classes it is often better to look at what they do, instead of just applying what one normally does. I did not even know this class and it is a bit unorthodox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authors of the class has chosen to automatically run the command `\pretextual` at the start of the document. This command is similar to `\frontmatter` and removed all headers and footers.

Thus start your document with `\mainmatter` or `\textual` to start a *normal* setup.

As mentioned in a comment. `memoir` (which this class is based on) has its own very well integrated system for handling headers and footers. `fancyhdr` should not be used with anything that runs on top of the `memoir` class.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your class (or one of the packages) do set the pagestyle at the begin of your document. Therefore putting `\pagestyle{fancy}` after `\begin{document}` works:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openright,twoside,a4paper,english,brazilian]{abntex2}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
         colorlinks,
         linkcolor={black!80!black},
         citecolor={blue!50!black},
         urlcolor={blue!80!black}
        }

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}

\let\footruleskip\undefined
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this has to do with the fact that abntex2 is based on memoir, and memoir has its own page header and footer mechanism, and is known not to work so well with fancyhdr.

Comment: Thank you @PietvanOostrum, for the explanation. I didn't know the class, so had to guess this fact more or less.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum nope: it starts the doc with its own version of `\frontmatter` and that version removes headers and footers. See around line 660 in the class file.

Comment: @Skillmon It worked, but only for even number pages. Still nothing on odd ones

Comment: @ThalesCastro you really should not use `fancyhdr` with `memoir`, what exactly are you trying to do, and why are you trying to change a class where the authors had a clear reasoning to do what they did

Comment: @ThalesCastro it works on even and on odd ones. Only on pages where a chapter begins it doesn't.

Comment: @daleif I diden't know that (i'm new to Latex). Worked fine.

Comment: @Skillmon Yes, my mistake. It's working now. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @ThalesCastro you should probably read the manual for this particular class. I cannot as it seems to be written in Portuguese